# How do I select the key of an object from a dropdown in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, use-state

I have a react page

```
myObject = {
  1: "objectValue"
}


function App() {
  const [myValue, setMyValue] = useState("")
  return ( <select className = "form-control"
    id = "valueToUse"
    onChange = {(event) => setMyValue(event.target.value)}
    value = {myValue}>{
      Object.keys(myObject).map((key) =>
        <option value = {key}> {myObject[key]} </option> 
      )
    }</select>
  )
}

export default App
```

But when I console.log(myValue) and select an option, nothing logs on the console. Please what could I be missing?

Comment: Some learning is missing !!! useState supposed to be under your function with a small f.

Comment: Can you post your actual code? If that is your code, you might want to look at how  react code is typically structured.

Comment: @SanishJoseph edited. An error when I was typing the question

Comment: lgtm, is there any error in the console? you should be seeing `1` as the output

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar I thought so too. But I'm not seeing anything

Comment: looks good now. Where is your console.log()? If it's inside the onChange, I don't see any immediate problem.

Comment: I think I know what's going on. I will add it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The setState in event handlers are batched in react. Meaning you will not see the change immediately. [You already have the value in hand from the event object, so you don't need the state value there anyway]

I have altered your code and you can see the useEffect console works perfectly while the console inside my event handler shows the previous value. To prove the point I added another value to myObject.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const myObject = {
  1: 'objectValue',
  2: 'objectValue2'
};

export default function App() {
  const [myValue, setMyValue] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect",myValue);
  }, [myValue]);

  return (
    <select
      className="form-control"
      id="valueToUse"
      onChange={event => {
        {
          setMyValue(event.target.value);
          console.log("EventHandler",myValue);
        }
      }}
      value={myValue}
    >
      {Object.keys(myObject).map(key => (
        <option value={key}> {myObject[key]} </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
}
```